# IntelliJ 2017.1.4 - Refusing to open terminal window

Tags: intellij-idea, terminal

I recently downloaded the latest version of IntelliJ Ultimate (at this time, it is 2017.1.4) for work.

For some reason, I cannot get it to open a new terminal window. When clicking the plus button here:

[image: IntelliJ Terminal tab view]

...nothing happens. Additionally, nothing shows up in the event log. I restarted IntelliJ, my computer, and did the "invalidate caches and restart" option.

Any ideas? Is there a log file I can look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @CrazyCoder for reminding me to check `idea.log` - the native terminal library, as well as other plugins, failed to initialize.

The root cause of the issue is that at my workplace, there is a security restriction to not run any executable that exists outside of `C:\Program Files`. As a result, IntelliJ cannot run certain plugins, jars, etc. that exist outside of that location, because it will attempt to execute them from your user directory.

To fix this, in IntelliJ, go to `Help > Edit Custom Properties` and point the `config` and `system` path to a known path where you can run executables, like so:

```
# custom IntelliJ IDEA properties

idea.config.path=C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\.IntelliJIdea2017.2\\config
idea.system.path=C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\.IntelliJIdea2017.2\\system
```

You will need to make sure to copy the contents of both directories to the new location. Hopefully this helps anyone else who runs into this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a [known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-172594) that is already [fixed in 2017.2](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/).

Another possible case is that the native terminal library fails to initialize on your system (check [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085) for exceptions). This can be caused by an antivirus or a corrupted IDE installation.